# Pegar hora local com JS, guardar no MySQL, mostrar com PHP

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Estou pegando a hora local com JavaScript na view, e enviando ao banco de dados.

O banco de dados esta armazenando essa data e hora como text.

A data e hora chega assim no banco de dados, ex.: 
Sun Nov 19 2017 07:19:39 GMT-0300 (Hora estÃ¡ndar de Argentina), um textão.

Quando eu quero mostrar essa data e hora em algum lugar, usando o PHP strtotime, e o date. A hora não aparece.

Sei que se a data e hora chegasse dessa maneira, ex.:

Sun Nov 19 2017 07:19:39 (sem o GMT e a hora standar...), funcionaria bem.

O que eu podeira fazer para resolver isso?

obs.: Sou novato na programação.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deixa a data da forma que você quer usando as funções `split()`, `slice()` e `join()`. Depois envie o formulário com essa data modificada.

Então ficaria da seguinte maneira:

```js
var date = new Date();
var dateFormat = date.toString().split(' ').slice(0, 5).join(' ');
console.log(dateFormat);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, Marcelo Junior.